# Problema com for e string.Remove

Tags: c#, .net, console

Estou tendo um problema com um programa que fiz para encriptação e decriptação a apartir de um hash, não julguem o funcionamento dele, fiz ele enquanto estava muito atoa.
O que não está funcionando é o decrypt, acredito que seja pela função `replacerbyhash()`, mas não consegui achar o problema.

Código:

```
else if(type.ToLower() == "decrypt")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite o hash.");
    hash = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Digite a mensagem encriptada.");
    txt = Console.ReadLine();
    replacerbyhash();
    replacer2();
}
```

Método Replacerbyhash:

```
static void replacerbyhash()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        az[i] = hash.Remove(i * 4, 4);
    }
}
```

Método Replacer2:

```
static void replacer2()
{
    txt = txt.Replace(az[0], "a");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[1], "b");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[2], "c");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[3], "d");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[4], "e");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[5], "f");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[6], "g");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[7], "h");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[8], "i");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[9], "j");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[10], "k");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[11], "l");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[12], "m");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[13], "n");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[14], "o");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[15], "p");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[16], "q");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[17], "r");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[18], "s");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[19], "t");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[20], "u");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[21], "v");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[22], "w");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[23], "x");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[24], "y");
    txt = txt.Replace(az[25], "z");
}
```

Como é feito o Hash:

```
static void compile()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        az[i] = x.Next(1000, 9999).ToString();
    }
}
```

Eu sei que o código está mal feito, eu não pensei muito para faze-lo.

Comment: pode postar um exemplo do hash e o exemplo de uma mensagem encriptada ?

Comment: É difícil falar alguma coisa só com esse trecho, o que posso dizer é que de fato não pra fazer algo bem mais simples, eficiente e menos trágico pro GC. E se entendi bem, está usando randômico pra "criptografar", aí eu acho que estaria só sujando o dado, ou seja, ninguém mais poderá usá-lo pra nada.

Comment: @bigown Sim, sei que estou fazendo da maneira errada, só fiz isso porque eu estava muito atoa na aula, esse código é inútil para mim. Mas mesmo assim esse problema que estou tendo me deixou um pouco curioso... [Código inteiro.](https://gist.github.com/ceifa/cf67d34f6d19a0870aa341146193488a)

Comment: @RovannLinhalis A palavra "test". 
Hash: `25373944232485139036550471698470496693739437688485855615330811538489511846224254934738599164124870343271`
Mensagem Encriptada: `4254903646224254`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentando entender o que você está fazendo, os valores do vetor seriam esses então (em negrito), o que está em italico foi removido pela função Remove():

az[0] = 
    *2537* **39442324851390365504716984704966937394376884858556153308‌​11538489511846224254‌​93473859916412487034‌​3271**

az[1] = 
    **2537** *3944* **2324851390365504716984704966937394376884858556153308‌​11538489511846224254‌​93473859916412487034‌​3271**

...e por ai vai...

talvez sua intenção fosse utilizar um SubString no lugar do remove, para que os valores ficassem assim:

az[0] = 2537 //a

az[1] = 3944 //b

```
c      d    e    f    g    h    i   j     k     l    m   n     o
2324 8513 9036 5504 7169 8470 4966 9373  9437 6884 8585 5615 3308‌ ​

 p     q    r   s    t    u    v     w    x    y    z
1153 8489 5118 4622 4254‌ ​9347 3859 9164 1248 7034‌ ​3271
```

Conferindo assim com o

```
test = 4254 9036 4622 4254
```

Então, basta atualizar sua função:

```
static void replacerbyhash()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        az[i] = hash.SubString(i * 4, 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu queria, não sabia da existência do Substring, obrigado.